# Show custom field value as a link

Tags: customization, links

I’m trying to show one of my custom fields as a link that downloads a photo. I’ve entered the URL in the field value but struggling to come up with the correct html to get it to display as a downloadable link.

```
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>License Type: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'License Type', true )."</li>";
echo "<li>Download Comp: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Download Comp, true )."</li>"; 
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

I’d like the ‘Download Comp’ to display ‘click here’ which would obviously be taken to the URL that I’ve already entered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>License Type: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'License Type', true )."</li>";
echo '<li><a href="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Download Comp', true ) . '">Download Comp</a></li>'; 
echo "</ul>";
?>
```